# redux-saga Network Error - OPTIONS request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've create a wizard form that I change a little bit. Each step of the form fetch some data from API when componentWillMount and when user click on "next" to go to the next form part, I call dispatch another action with componentWillUnmout to dispatch an Update (PUT) action from the API.

I'm using redux-saga with react.

Here is the saga.js file :

```
import { call, put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import accountApi from '../../api/account';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

import {
    FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
    FETCH_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS,
    UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS
} from '../../actions/types';

export function* fetchAccount(action) {
    const account = yield call(accountApi.fetchAccount, action.params);
    yield put({ type: FETCH_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, account: account });
}

export function* updateAccount(action) {
    const accountUpdated = yield call(accountApi.updateAccount, action.params, action.accountUpdated);
    yield put({ type: UPDATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, accountUpdated: accountUpdated });
}

export function* accountListener() {
    yield takeEvery(FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST, fetchAccount);
    yield takeEvery(UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST, updateAccount);
}
```

There is the API file :

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseUrl = '<link>';

const accountApi = {
    fetchAccount(params) {
        return axios.get(`${baseUrl}${params}`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.data
            })
    },

    updateAccount(params, accountUpdated) {
        return axios.put(`${baseUrl}${params}`, accountUpdated)
            .then(response => {
                return response.data
            })
    }
}

export default accountApi;
```

the action :

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
    FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST
} from './types';

export function fetchAccount(params) {
    return {
        type: FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
        params
    }
}

export function updateAccount(params, accountUpdated) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
        params,
        accountUpdated
    }
}
```

the reducer :

```
import { 
    FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST, 
    FETCH_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS, 
    UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ACCOUNT_REQUEST:
            return null;
        case FETCH_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
            return action.account;
        case UPDATE_ACCOUNT_REQUEST:
            return null;
        case UPDATE_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS:
            return action.accountUpdated;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And the component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import validate from './validate';

class FormGlobalInformations extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const fakeAccountId = '?accountId=0012400000oAMhY';
        this.props.actions.fetchAccount(fakeAccountId);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.account) {
            this.props.initialize({
                companyName: this.props.account.companyName,
                typologie: this.props.account.typologie,
                phone: this.props.account.phone
            });
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        const fakeAccountId = '?accountId=0012400000oAMhY';
        this.props.actions.updateAccount(fakeAccountId, this.props.form.Information.values);
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Field 
                        label="Nom de l'établissement"
                        name="companyName"
                        type="text"
                        className="form-group"
                        component={this.renderFields}
                    />
                    <Field 
                        label="Type d'établissement : "
                        name="typologie"
                        component={this.renderSelect}
                        className="form-group"
                    />
                    <Field 
                        label="Votre numéro de téléphone de contact"
                        name="phone"
                        type="number"
                        className="form-group"
                        component={this.renderFields}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-tiller-full btn-tiller-right">Suite</button>
            </form>
        );  
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        account: state.account,
        form: state.form
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
}

FormGlobalInformations = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FormGlobalInformations);

FormGlobalInformations = reduxForm({
    form: 'Information',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    validate
})(FormGlobalInformations);

export default FormGlobalInformations;
```

(The next form step component is the same so I fetch data onmount and I update on unmount).

Here is the index.js file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
// import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reducers from './reducers';

// Components
import Informations from './components/Informations/Informations';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Header from './components/Navigation/Header';

import { accountListener } from './services/account/saga';

function* RootListener() {
    yield all([
        accountListener()
    ]);
}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
);

sagaMiddleware.run(RootListener);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Navigation />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/informations" component={Informations} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('.container-fluid')
);
```

Here is the error that I have when I try to update :
[image]

And I have a OPTIONS request...

Someone could help ?

Comment: Maybe is a CORS plus webserver issue and not a client one? I think about CORS because you have an OPTIONS here.
Keep in mind that some webserver (nginx for example) needs you to configure HTTP verb like OPTIONS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update (PUT) action from the API.
>
> And I have a OPTIONS request...

Most likely that issue is not dependent on `redux-saga`, because error occurs in `axios` call inside. Supposed preconditions with `PUT` verb affects mandatory `OPTIONS` preflight query, which returns available `CORS` politics for request origin. It's mandatory because of `PUT` is state-changing verb, so returning allowance HTTP header, like in `GET`-requests, is very late, that's why independent preflight query is used.

Read more here [How to apply CORS preflight cache to an entire domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013216/how-to-apply-cors-preflight-cache-to-an-entire-domain) and here [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Simplest solution **without** preflight query provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373949/7878274