# Clearing the cached preflight response on Firefox

Tags: caching, cors, browser-cache

I am using a CDN in between my server and client(browser) to cache my ajax requests.

Along with the usual headers, I am also setting the Access-Control-Max-Age header to cache the preflight request.(OPTIONS Request)

How do I remove the cached response from my Firefox Browser?

The normal Ctrl + Shift + Delete and clearing the cache is not clearing the cached response.

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check content of preflight result cache in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815842/how-to-check-content-of-preflight-result-cache-in-firefox)